# Expectation from a colour-matching withdrawal game

Tags: probability, expectation

> A person draws 3 balls from a bag containing 3 white, 4 red and 5 black balls. He is offered 10 bucks, 5 bucks, 2 bucks if he draws 3 ball of same color, 2 balls of same color and 1 ball of each color respectively. Find how much he expects to earn.

I tried to solve this question by calculating probability of getting 3 balls of same color that came $3/44$ but for solving balls of 2 same colors there are so many combination and calculation becomes lengthy so is there any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation for "2 balls of the same colour" isn't that hard. Suppose the same-coloured balls are white; there are $\binom32$ ways to pick the white balls and 9 choices for the last, non-white ball. Similarly for the red and black balls, leading to
$$\frac{9\binom32+8\binom42+7\binom52}{\binom{12}3}=\frac{29}{44}$$
By complementation, the probability that three different-colour balls are picked is $\frac3{11}$ and the expectation falls quickly:
$$E=10\cdot\frac3{44}+5\cdot\frac{29}{44}+2\cdot\frac3{11}=\frac{199}{44}=4.5227\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

You had a good start. The expected value is calculated from the sum of the probability and the value associated with that probability.

So, the expected value here would be the following:

$10$ $ 3 \choose 3 $ $12 \choose 3$^-1  + $10$$4 \choose 3$ $2 \choose 3$^-1 + $10$ $5 \choose 3$ $12 \choose 3$^-1  + $5$$ 3 \choose 2 $ $ 9 \choose 1$ $12 \choose 3$^-1 + $5$$4 \choose 2$ $8 \choose 1 $ $12 \choose 3$^-1 + $5$ $  5 \choose 2$ $7 \choose 1$ $12 \choose 3$^-1 + $ 3 \choose 1 $ $4 \choose 1$ $5 \choose 1$) $*12 \choose 3$^-1.

Which, all laid out is:

$10 times the probability of drawing the three balls respectively,

$5 times the probability of drawing two of the same and one different ball respectively,

and $1 times the probability of drawing all different balls.

Happy studying!

Answer (score 1):

As you presumably found, there are ${12\choose3}=220$ ways to choose $3$ balls altogether, of which there are ${3\choose3}+{4\choose3}+{5\choose3}=1+4+10=15$ ways to choose them all of the same color.  It's also straightforward to count the number of ways of choose one ball of each color:  ${3\choose1}{4\choose1}{5\choose1}=60$.  This leaves

$$220-15-60=145$$

as the number of ways to choose two balls of the same color (and the third of another).  Thus the expected value for your game is

$$10\cdot{15\over220}+5\cdot{145\over220}+2\cdot{60\over220}={199\over44}$$

The key thing to realize here is that the three possibilities are mutually exclusive and account for *everything* that can happen, so if you can easily compute the probability for two of them, the probability for the third can be computed by complementarity.